# ¿Por qué las listas de java no se devuelven a si mismas en la función add()?

Tags: java

Me gustaria saber cual es el motivo por el cual la función `add()` de una lista devuelve un booleano en lugar de devolver la misma lista,  me parece que lo segundo seria más practico ¿Hay un motivo por el cuál esto sea así?

```
List<Objeto> lobjeto = new ArrayList();
objeto.add(new Objeto()); ---> estó devuelve un booleano
```

Comment: Básicamente te devuelve true si se pudo insertar y false si no, me parece. Por si hay conflicto de tipos o similar

Comment: Si hubiera conflicto de tipos daría error de compilación

Comment: No todos los programadores que utilicen listas necesitan que despues de agregar algo a dicha lista, retorne la misma, eso seria generalizar y parcializar a necesidad de unos pocos programadores los metodos de esa clase. Por eso tu puedes crear una clase  y modificar a tu gusto solo hazle el extends de la clase de lista que quieras y haz que retorne lo que necesites.

Comment: Primero que nada, si retorna "true" ya sabes que tu lista inicial tiene ese elemento, por lo que no hay motivo para que te retorne la lista con el nuevo elemento, porque seria justamente la misma lista. En segundo lugar, para los casos donde el add falle, que prefieres, chequear por "false" o recorrer la lista resultado y ver si se inserto (o chequear el size o algo similar , pero igual de poco determinista) ?

Comment: @gibranalexismorenozuñiga Para que el usuario le llegue tu comentario, siempre debes poner el arroba `@`... `@nombre_de_usuario`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los creadores originales de Java (Sun Microsystems a.k.a Oracle of America) no eran muy amigos de las interfaces fluidas, si revisas los JDK del 1.1 al 1.4 te darás cuenta que hay muy pocas (creo que menos de 50) clases con interfaces fluidas. Como dice @michel-escalante-álvarez, es cuestión de estilo y aunque tú lo consideres buena práctica ahora es muy probable que en su momento existieran razones de peso para no hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

No existe un motivo como tal, simplemente el desarrollador de Oracle que programó la función tomo esa decisión. No entiendo qué te causa dudas. Recuerda que para un problema no existe una única solución, y lo que te resulta conveniente a ti en una situación no lo es así siempre. Imagina que Java estuviese implementado de esa forma y que quisieras saber si un elemento fue insertado en la lista... Tendrías que recorrerla para comprobarlo y en ese caso lo que tu llamas "práctico" no lo seria.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy de acuerdo contigo, no es necesario que devuelva la lista porque al llamar a .add() tu lista ya está actualizada con ese nuevo componente.

Answer (score 0):

El Java Collections framework añade el metodo abstracto

```
boolean add(E element)
```

El cual retorna si el elemento se pudo añadir a tu coleccion, para tu caso puntual List y sus implementaciones ArrayList,LinkedList, retornaran true cada vez que lo invoques, ya que permite elementos duplicados.